# Erro ao carregar Widget Dialog() jQuery em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu instalei o jQueryUI, alterei o meu BundleConfig, mas mesmo assim o browser não reconhece o Widget Dialog() do meu script **jquery.dialogo.js**. Verifiquei se a biblioteca está sendo carregada e está tudo normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**BundleConfig**

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dialogo.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
}
```

**Script**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#excluir").click(function () {
            $("#dialogo").dialog();
        })
    })
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Erro**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

Aqui você já possui um **Bundle** para o **jQuery**.

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Sendo assim, você não precisa referenciar o mesmo no **Bundle** para o **jQuery-UI**. Me refiro à isto:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js",//não há necessidade disso
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dialogo.js"));
```

Altere para isso:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dialogo.js"));
```

E em sua `view` principal, **_Layout.cstml** você está referenciando os arquivos, porém na ordem "errada". Você precisa referenciar primeiro o **jQuery** e após referenciar o script do **jQuery-UI**, ficando assim o seu **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Randrade, fiz as alterações como sugeriu e também na minha viu eu acrescentei @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
} e agora está funcionando, mas quando tiro esse render e deixo apenas no Layout ele não funciona, eu poderia colocar os Rendes do Layout depois do Styles para não ter que referenciar novamente esses scrips em cada View? Um dos objetivos em usar o Layout é evitar repetir essa referência de scripts em cada View.

Comment: Teoricamente era para funcionar nas outras `views`. Você pode verificar a ordem que está sendo passado, ou se aparece algum erro no **console**. Mas, não faz sentido carregar um `script` se você não for usar, não concorda?

Comment: Onde não precisa ele não acusa erro, só onde eu uso algum tema, mas vou evitar de mexer nele e deixa como está. Tenho que tentar colocar para rodar o widget na exclusão de registro. Obrigada mais uma vez Randrade!

Answer (score 3):

Além do que o @Randrade citou, pode acontecer o seguinte;

O bundle normalmente segue uma sequencia alfabética, o que pode acontecer de alguns scripts necessários estarem sendo carregados posteriormente.

O que você pode fazer é:

Dentro de seu arquivo `BundleConfig.cs` criar uma nova `BundleOrder`

```
class MinhaNovaBundleOrder: IBundleOrderer {
      public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
      {
        return files;
      }
}
```

E usa-la da seguinte forma:

```
meusScripts  = new MinhaNovaBundleOrder();
meusScripts.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/all").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js",//não há necessidade disso
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dialogo.js"));
```

Criando dessa forma, você terá um único `bundle` para todos os seus arquivos .js, seguindo a ordem que você colocou em seu `bundle`.

Comment: Rod obrigada pela sugestão.

Comment: @KellySoares teste ambas resposta, caso ainda não resolva, informe.